# Angular/Angular2 get headers from ActivatedRoute

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, routes, http-headers

I have an Angular app hosted within an IFrame.  I have to retrieve some user details that are passed from the application hosting the IFrame e.g. userId=12345.

Is there a way to retrieve header details from Activated route or similar?

Comment: i am tying the same thing

Comment: @Steve Fitzsimons were you able to find any solution for this problem?